# Capture UIView in RubyMotion

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, uiimage, rubymotion

I want to capture an UIView as an UIImage. I've tried many things, but I always get this *kind* of error :

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

Here is my captureView method :

```
  def captureView
    rect = view.bounds
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext
    view.layer(renderInContext:context)
    img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext
    img
  end
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is there another way to capture images ?

Thanks.

Comment: that is not objective -c . IS that swift ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, @elie-teyssedou, that the thread you're running this code on has something to do with it.

I've seen this error when taking "snapshot specs" (FBSnapshotSpec), which I'm pretty sure are not running on the main thread.  I haven't tested the theory, because the code actually works despite the error messages.

Other than that, the code you're using looks fine, so I suspect it's something going on with the environment you're running the code it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: To run it on the main thread, you run this code inside a dispatch queue on the main thread: `Dispatch::Queue.main.async do ...(screenshot code)... end`

Answer (score 0):

this is what I use

```
  def self.convert_view_to_image(view)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, true, 0.0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    image
  end
```

Comment: It produce the same, but thanks anyway, now I know that it's not a common issue.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.